# Compute the sum of the series

Tags: java, math, series

I'm having a trouble finding an algorithm or understanding this question to be honest.
I've searched online but none of the answers I've found helped.
The Question Says:
Write a method to compute the sum of the series in a class called SpecialSeries.
The signature of the method is:

```
public static double sumOfSeries(double x, int numTerms)
```

[This is the Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsrMw.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't exactly an appropriate SO question. But, I did find this if you wanna check it out, hopefully it will push you in the right direction: https://github.com/java-tester-x/javaexercises/blob/master/difficult/SpecialSeries.java

Comment: The best place to start would be doing some of this out by hand. I would suggest starting with a value of X and walking through the series by hand, that might give you a hint of how to approach the problem.

Comment: So far, using a for loop (with a counter=number of terms) and adding the x value to an the result variable, but i don't think this is what the question asks me to do. this is where i need help.

Comment: http://github.com/java-tester-x/javaexercises/blob/master/difficult/SpecialSeries.java#L37-L49

Comment: I don't have any problems coding it, I'm just not familiar with series.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)

Comment: That's not helpful ...

Comment: The variable part seems to be (x^(2n-1))/(2n-1) Where n goes from 1 to n. The constant part is a little trickier.

Comment: If you understand how to code it, just not what it means by "series", then you need to show us the code that you do understand.  Throwing only the problem statement up and asking us to do your homework is not going to help you learn how to do it.  (BTW, do you see that `x` and multiplication are two different things in that image?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is enough to compute your serie:

```
public static double sumOfSeries(double x, int numTerms){
   double result = 0;
   if(x<=1 && x>=-1){ 
      double startval=3;
      for(int i=0; i<numTerms-1;i++){                    
         result+= (double)(oddevenfact(startval-2)/oddevenfact(startval-1))*(Math.pow(x, startval)/startval);
         startval+=2;
      }
      if(numTerms!=0) result+=x;
   }
   return result;
}

static double oddevenfact(double x){
   if (x>2) return(oddevenfact(x-2) * (long) x);
   return((double) x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpecialSeries {
    public static double SumOfSeries(double x, int numTerms) {
        if (numTerms == 1) {
            return x;
        }
        int maxOdd = numTerms * 2 - 1;
        int maxEven = numTerms * 2 - 2;
        double powerTerm = Math.pow(x, maxOdd) / maxOdd;
        int numerator = 1;
        for (int numMult = maxOdd - 2; numMult > 2; numMult -= 2) {
            numerator *= numMult;
        }
        int denominator = 2;
        for (int numMult = maxEven; numMult > 2; numMult -= 2) {
            denominator *= numMult;
        }
        return powerTerm * numerator / denominator + sumOfSeries(x, numTerms - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int numTerms = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            double x = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
            System.out.println(sumOfSeries(x, numTerms));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **mathematic stuff**

first lets check out your series:
  [image: the special series as sum of terms]
So your series can be represented as follows:
[image]
with :
[image]

now, we can do more math simplification, or go ahead for the implimentation

2. **Java implimenttion**

   ```
    public class SpecialSeries {

       public static double sumOfSeries(double x, int numTerms){
           double sum = x;
           //System.out.println("u["+0+"] = "+x);
           for (int k = 1; k < numTerms; k++) {
               double uk = Math.pow(x,2*k+1)/(double)(2*k+1);
               for (int i = 2*k-1; i >0; i-=2) {
                   uk *= i/(double)(i+1);
               }
               //System.out.println("u["+k+"] = "+uk);
               sum += uk;
           }        
           return sum;
       }  

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(sumOfSeries(1, 5));
       }
    }
   ```